# Get all categories of posts

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

i m using Codeigniter. I wanted to show all posts with their respective categories. i have made a code but it is only showing one category of the post. why my code is not getting all the categories of the post? any solution or improvement will be good. here are my codes:

```
$this->db->select("posts.*, categories.*");
$this->db->from( 'posts' );

//get cats
$this->db->join('post_cat', 'posts.post_id = post_cat.post_id', 'LEFT');
$this->db->join('categories', 'post_cat.cat_id = post_cat.cat_id', 'LEFT');

//get published blogs
$this->db->where('post_type', 'blog');
$this->db->where('post_status', 'published');

$this->db->group_by("posts.post_id");
$this->db->order_by("post_id", "desc");

$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: Just a guess since I don't know codeigniter syntax... You use `GROUP BY post.post_id`  so I believe you need to use `GROUP_CONCAT` for `post_cat` table rows (if there is 0...n relationship between post and categories as there seems to be). Or don't use `GROUP BY` at all...

Comment: without records hard to help

Comment: @ZZ-bb if you don't know codeigniter then here is the SQL: SELECT `posts`.*, `categories`.* FROM (`posts`) LEFT JOIN `post_cat` ON `post_cat`.`post_id` = `posts`.`post_id` LEFT JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`cat_id` = `post_cat`.`cat_id` WHERE `post_type` = 'news' AND `post_status` = 'published' GROUP BY `posts`.`post_id` ORDER BY `post_id` desc

Answer (score 0):

I guess you did a **typo** here.

**Try below code:**

```
$this->db->select("posts.*, categories.*");
$this->db->from( 'posts' );

//get cats
$this->db->join('post_cat', 'posts.post_id = post_cat.post_id', 'LEFT');
$this->db->join('categories', 'post_cat.cat_id = categories.id', 'LEFT');
// you did typo in above statement here ==> post_cat.cat_id = post_cat.cat_id

//get published blogs
$this->db->where('post_type', 'blog');
$this->db->where('post_status', 'published');

$this->db->group_by("posts.post_id");
$this->db->order_by("post_id", "desc");

$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: yes i have corrected this typo few mins ago but nothing happens. to make you more clear here are my sql tables and queries: http://pastie.org/9883714 http://pastie.org/9883717

Comment: Both of your `post_id` is the same in `post_cat` table. In this case remove the `group_by`

Comment: you did not given the right suggestions anyways i found the solution for it!

Comment: then you should share the answer for others to use. (You can answer your own question)

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution and here it is:

```
//select posts,cats,tags
$this->db->select("posts.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT categories.cat_slug,'-',categories.cat_name) as cat",FALSE);
$this->db->from('posts');

//join cats
$this->db->join('post_cat', 'post_cat.post_id = posts.post_id', 'LEFT');
$this->db->join('categories', 'categories.cat_id = post_cat.cat_id', 'LEFT');

//get published blog
$this->db->where('post_type', 'blog');
$this->db->where('post_status', 'published');

$this->db->group_by("posts.post_id");
$this->db->order_by("post_id", "desc");

$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result_array();
```